# jspeex, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in android

Tags: android, jspeex

I am using `jspeex.jar` in android when i try to compile it is throwing error

```
12-01 11:30:58.998: E/AndroidRuntime(17989): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.xiph.speex.SpeexEncoder
```

[In this link](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-updates-questions/20207-problem-creating-library-i-keep-getting-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-error.html) they suggested to use @DependsOn(value = {"jspeex"}) but it is showing error. i am using eclipse on ubuntu with openjdk-6.

i am posting the log it may give you better picture of my problem

```
12-01 11:30:58.898: E/dalvikvm(17989): Could not find class 'org.xiph.speex.OggSpeexWriter', referenced from method com.samsung.sample.jspeex.JSpeexSampleActivity.encodeFile
12-01 11:30:58.898: W/dalvikvm(17989): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 50 (Lorg/xiph/speex/OggSpeexWriter;) in Lcom/samsung/sample/jspeex/JSpeexSampleActivity;
12-01 11:30:58.898: W/dalvikvm(17989): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 71: Lorg/xiph/speex/AudioFileWriter;.close ()V
12-01 11:30:58.898: W/dalvikvm(17989): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 71: Lorg/xiph/speex/AudioFileWriter;.close ()V
12-01 11:30:58.898: W/dalvikvm(17989): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 71: Lorg/xiph/speex/AudioFileWriter;.close ()V
12-01 11:30:58.908: W/dalvikvm(17989): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 71: Lorg/xiph/speex/AudioFileWriter;.close ()V
12-01 11:30:58.908: E/dalvikvm(17989): Could not find class 'org.xiph.speex.SpeexEncoder', referenced from method com.samsung.sample.jspeex.JSpeexSampleActivity.initEncoder
12-01 11:30:58.908: W/dalvikvm(17989): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 51 (Lorg/xiph/speex/SpeexEncoder;) in Lcom/samsung/sample/jspeex/JSpeexSampleActivity;
12-01 11:30:58.998: W/dalvikvm(17989): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8)
12-01 11:30:58.998: E/AndroidRuntime(17989): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 11:30:58.998: E/AndroidRuntime(17989): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.xiph.speex.SpeexEncoder
12-01 11:30:58.998: E/AndroidRuntime(17989):    at com.samsung.sample.jspeex.JSpeexSampleActivity.initEncoder(JSpeexSampleActivity.java:99)
12-01 11:30:58.998: E/AndroidRuntime(17989):    at com.samsung.sample.jspeex.JSpeexSampleActivity.onCreate(JSpeexSampleActivity.java:52)
12-01 11:30:58.998: E/AndroidRuntime(17989):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-01 11:30:58.998: E/AndroidRuntime(17989):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
12-01 11:30:58.998: E/AndroidRuntime(17989):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
12-01 11:30:58.998: E/AndroidRuntime(17989):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
12-01 11:30:58.998: E/AndroidRuntime(17989):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
12-01 11:30:58.998: E/AndroidRuntime(17989):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-01 11:30:58.998: E/AndroidRuntime(17989):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-01 11:30:58.998: E/AndroidRuntime(17989):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
12-01 11:30:58.998: E/AndroidRuntime(17989):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 11:30:58.998: E/AndroidRuntime(17989):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-01 11:30:58.998: E/AndroidRuntime(17989):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
12-01 11:30:58.998: E/AndroidRuntime(17989):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-01 11:30:58.998: E/AndroidRuntime(17989):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can any body help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @nfechner thanx for editing the code i was trying the same